# How to consolidate data from multiple Excel rows all into one row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of IDs and corresponding variables. Since I have the same IDs listed in multiple rows in my ID column (e.g. ID 37 in A1, A2, and A3), I want to have one row per ID in the column (ID only in A1 and all corresponding variables in columns B1, C1, etc., then ID only in A2 and all corresponding varibales in B2, C2, etc.).

In order to do this I created more variables with _2, _3, _4 across the top of my spreadsheet. Now for each ID I want to move the data into the top row for each ID and delete the remaining rows for the ID so that each ID is only listed once in column A.

I've been copying and pasting to the top row then deleting the extra rows. I have 882 IDs so this is taking forever. How can I automate it?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d

Answer (score 0):

excel has a consolidate function , in the data tab (excel 2013) click consolidate, select the range of your data, then select the column with the id, the operation to be done (sum) and thats it